# Complexity .. Big O

Tags: c++, big-o, complexity-theory

I have to determine the time complexity (big O) of the following function:

```
void BET::makeEmpty(BinaryNode* &n)
{
    if(n != NULL)
    {
        makeEmpty(n->left);
        makeEmpty(n->right);
        delete n;
    }
    n = NULL;
}
```

I am familiar with time complexity for simple functions (for loops, nested loops, etc) but I am unsure how to determine the big O for a recursive function.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the format of your question is more suited for Programming department of stackexchange network. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, being a general question about complexity of recursive functions. It would sound more concrete, if you outlined a business purposes behind determining the complexity in this case. Theory without any practical use does not make any sense. Having said all that, check this out: http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html

Answer (score 4):

Well, this one is easier than you think: `makeEmpty` perform a constant (`O(1)`) amount of work (excluding the recursive calls, of course). It'll run exactly one time on each node in the tree. So its time complexity is `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of nodes in the tree.

Comment: so just O(n) will be the answer ?

Comment: @user2267975: yes, the operation will be executed once per node, given  n node you will preform n operations, so it is O(n)

Comment: Actually it's also omega(n). O(n) and Omega(n) => Theta(n)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the **recurrence relation** of your algorithm should look like the following:

[image]

Are you able to solve it?